# Issue installing python bcrypt in Cygwin

Tags: python, rust, pip, cygwin, bcrypt

I'm trying to install paramiko in Cygwin and one of the build dependencies is bcrypt.
I have rustc installed and I believe all of the supporting build libraries.

Pip is also updated to the latest.

```
$ pip --version
pip 22.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I use the following pip command:

```
pip install bcrypt
```

And I get the following error output:

```
  error: failed to run custom build command for `pyo3-build-config v0.15.2`

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Cygwin64\tmp\pip-install-19d9dusl\bcrypt_117761e212a240d8804ceae0beeb39c1\src\_bcrypt\target\release\build\pyo3-build-config-2ef06b5f5d02e46b\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
    --- stdout
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_CONFIG_FILE
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_NO_PYTHON
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_PYTHON

    --- stderr
    error: failed to run the Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python.exe: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/_bcrypt/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/abi3-py36 pyo3/extension-module -- --crate-type cdylib

      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install bcrypt:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed. bcrypt requires
         rustc >= 1.56.0.

      Python: 3.8.12
      platform: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044-3.3.5-341.x86_64-x86_64-64bit-WindowsPE
      pip: n/a
      setuptools: 65.3.0
      setuptools_rust: 1.5.1
      rustc: 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

  error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/_bcrypt/Cargo.toml --release -v --features 'pyo3/abi3-py36 pyo3/extension-module' -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for bcrypt Failed to build bcrypt ERROR: Could not build wheels for bcrypt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I check my python installation (python.exe) and it is installed at /usr/bin/python.exe.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python.exe        /usr/bin/python2.7.exe   /usr/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/bin/python2-config    /usr/bin/python3         /usr/bin/python3.8.exe
/usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3-config
```

So I am confused.....what is the issue? Why can't it find my python interpreter? Why is bcrypt not building and installing?

Comment: Did you see the DEBUG ASSISTANCE instructions there? Maybe try those first.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm running the latest pip and rustc. Still produces the same error,

Comment: Ok there was no indication in your question that you had already done so. What is the output of `python -vV`?

Comment: Cygwin may be causing the issues here. They appear to have their own [packaged version of `python-bcrypt`](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python36-bcrypt.html)

Comment: @PitaJ I liked your most recent answer. That was the fix for the issue. I installed the cygwin package for python38-bcrypt and then it installed successfully

Comment: You are mixing up python2 and python3 here. You need to be using python3. Use `python -V`,`python2 -V` and/or `python3 -V` to find out which command runs python version 3. Then use the right command to run pip: `pythonX -m pip ...`. Always make sure cygwin is fully up to date. Always check if there is a cygwin package for a python package because it will have cygwin specific patches.

Comment: @Doug. I confirmed the version invoked is python3. The cygwin package route was really the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that Cygwin causes some compatibility issues here.

It looks like Cygwin has a package for this purpose, likely to avoid these issues:

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python36-bcrypt.html

Comment: cygwin has multiple special python packages that should be installed through cygwin and not pip. Cygwin has a paramiko package instead of using pip install paramiko